# Modal PopUp - Asp.Net Ajax control toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm using a ModalPopUp in an Asp.net application and would like to have it closing automaticaly when user clicks "esc".

I've used the following script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad() {
        $addHandler(document, 'keydown', onKeypress);
    }

    function onKeypress(args) {

        if (args.keyCode == Sys.UI.Key.esc) {

            var mdl = $find('modalExtender').hide();

        }
    }

</script>
```

And the Modal Extender is declared like that:

```
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender 
            ID="modalExtender" 
            runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="btnPreview"
            PopupControlID="PreviewPanel"
            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
            DropShadow="true"
            CancelControlID="btnFechar" />
```

When I press the "esc" key I'm getting this error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object"

Has someone had the same problem? How was it solved?
Thank you in advance.

Josimari Martarelli

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: [link text](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/how_to_dismiss_a_modalpopup_us.html)

Answer (score 0):

This may work for both IE and Moozilla

document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;  


function KeyCheck(e)
{
     //Ternary check to cover FF or IE
     var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
     if (KeyID = '27') {
 
         //Close Popup
         var mdl = $find('modalExtender').hide();
    }
}

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I'm still getting the same error message when displaying the page in IE and it doesn't work in Firefox.

    function pageLoad() {
        document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;
    }


    function KeyCheck(e) {
        //Ternary check to cover FF or IE
        var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
        if (KeyID = '27') {
            //Close Popup
            var mdl = $find('modalExtender').hide();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your $find be looking for the control PreviewPanel instead of the extender?  I believe your $find is returning a null because there is no HTML control with the name modalExtender.

Also, you probably need to get the ClientId for PreviewPanel instead of the ASP.NET Control name (if my guess that PreviewPanel is an ASP.NET Control is correct).

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, I was missing the BehaviorID of the ModalPopUp...